# Approximation of $\log(x)$ as a linear combination of $\log(2)$ and $\log(3)$

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

I wonder if it's possible to approximate $\log(n)$, n integer, by using a linear combination of $\log(2)$ and $\log(3)$.

More formally, given integer $n$ and and real $\epsilon>0$, is it always possible to find integer $x,a,b$ where:

$$\left|n^x-2^a 3^b\right|<\epsilon$$

For example, I can approximate $11$ by $$2^{-33} 3^{23}=10.959708460955880582332611083984375 \approx 10.96.$$

Comment: Interesting! +1 But, to what end?

Comment: Since $n^x$ and $2^a3^b$ are both integers, the absolute value of their difference will never be less than 1. You probably mean the difference of their logarithms.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ could be negative integers, that can make differences less than 1.

Comment: @Pedro There is an interesting connection to music theory. An octave is the frequency ratio $2:1$, and a perfect fifth is $3:2$, so the combination of $s$ octaves and $t$ fifths corresponds to $2^{s-t}3^b$. A natural question is "What (nice) intervals can we approximate using combinations of octaves and fifths?" The result is [Pythagorean tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tuning), where a major third, for example, is $81:64$ instead of the usual $5:4$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

Let $a=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}$. Then, $a$ is irrational, thus by Dirichclet Theorem, the set $\{ ma+n | m,n \in Z \}$ is dense. Thus, there exists some $m,n \in Z$ so that

$$\left| \frac{\log(n)}{\log(3)} - ma -k \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{\log(3)}$$

Multiply by $\log(3)$ and you are done.

**P.S.** It is irrelevant that $n$ is integer. Also, the proof works if you replace $2$ and $3$ by any numbers $x,y$ so that $\log_x(y)$ is irrational.

**P.P.S.** I think that for $n$ positive **integer**, it is enough to use one $\log(2)$. Indeed, if $n$ is a power of 2, you are done, otherwise, $\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}$ is irrational, and then the set $m\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)} - k$ is dense. Thus, you can find some integers so that

$$\left|m\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)} - k  \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{\log(2)}$$

Of course, you get rational coefficients in this case.

Comment: Thanks! That settles my curiosity :)