# Can I find any value super close to some value with combination of two numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I hope this is not a silly question.

Suppose there is a collection of {$x^{a}y^{b}$}$_{(a,b)}$ where $x\in(0,1)$, $y>1$, and  $a$ and $b$ can be any natural numbers.

I was wondering if I can always find $\epsilon$-close real number to any value in $(0,1)$, if there is no rational number $c$ such that $x^c = y$.

---

This is what I've tried. Suppose we can approximate $x^{a}y^{b}$ to some value $D\in(0,1)$ .

Then, it means there exists $a$ and $b$ such that

$$\log D \approx a* \log (x) + b *\log(y)$$

Which again implies that

$$\frac{\log D}{\log(x)} \approx a + b \frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)}$$

$\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)}$ is assumed to be a negative irrational number and  $\frac{\log(D)}{\log(x)}$ is any positive number.

Essentially, I think I'm asking if I can make a positive-valued dense set with two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ and a negative irrational number.

I could find Dirichlet's theorem and the following Q&A.

[Approximation of $\log(x)$ as a linear combination of $\log(2)$ and $\log(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160014/approximation-of-logx-as-a-linear-combination-of-log2-and-log3/160016#160016)

However, therein, $a$ and $b$ are allowed to be integers.